# Remove Logs from PyQt5 Browser on Console

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a PyQt5 application [Virtual Desktop](https://github.com/DSSecret-Studios-Dev/Virtual-Desktop) that has a built-in browser. When I use the browser, I get JS errors from the browser similar to how Chrome puts JS and HTML errors in the "Web Inspector". How do I get rid of those errors.

To replicate the errors, download [Virtual Desktop](https://github.com/DSSecret-Studios-Dev/Virtual-Desktop) and install PyQt from PYPI. You'll need to run `main.py`, select a QStyle, and click on the Browser (next to the power button). Go to any website (google for example) and switch back to your console. You will notice that the console is populated with JS errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not observe the problem when using your project but I had this problem before and the solution was to write the `javaScriptConsoleMessage()` method, eliminating the default behavior.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets 

class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, line, sourceID):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    page = WebEnginePage(view)
    view.setPage(page)
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com/"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would implement your solution in my program because the browser (and all the other applications) are `QMdiSubWindow`. Because of that, my program is designed differently than yours.

Comment: @DS_SecretStudios I made you a PR, check your repository