# Select points from Folium map in a PyQt5 widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium, qwebengineview

I am fairly new to pyqt5 but I am able to display a **Folium map** using the PyQt5 **QWebEngineView** widget, and I can place a button on top of the map.

I want to be able to click the button and that the next click on the map saves the place where I clicked, i.e the **lat,lon** coordinates. But I do not know how to interact with the map in that manner.

I tried obtaining the position of the click in terms of pixels, but I can not translate it to lat,lon because I can not obtain the coordinates of the bounds of the map at the moment I click, note that the map can be moved around with the cursor too. Thank you for your help

```
class FoliumDisplay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Folium map in PyQt')
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        coordinate = (51.301100, 5.272991)
        m = folium.Map(
            tiles='Stamen Terrain',
            zoom_start=4,
            location=coordinate)
        # save map data to data object
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)

        webView = QWebEngineView() # start web engine
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode()) #give html of folium map to webengine
        layout.addWidget(webView)

        #### CEATE SELECT  BUTTON
        self.button_select_point = QPushButton(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bauhaus 93")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_select_point.setFont(font)
        self.button_select_point.setGeometry(QRect(100,20,200,50))
        self.button_select_point.setText("Select one point")
        self.button_select_point.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_select_point)

    def clicked_button_select_point(self):
        print("Clicked")
```

Answer (score 1):

folium is made to produce HTML based on the previous settings but it unnecessarily complicates the communication between the page events and Qt. In these cases it is better to implement the logic using QtWebChannel where a QObject is used to exchange the information.

```py
import json
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class MapManager(QtCore.QObject):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def receive_data(self, message, json_data):
        data = json.loads(json_data)
        if message == "click":
            self.clicked.emit(data["lat"], data["lng"])


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._was_clicked = False

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        map_manager = MapManager(self)
        channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(view)
        channel.registerObject("map_manager", map_manager)
        view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
        filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "index.html")
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        view.load(url)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(view)

        map_manager.clicked.connect(self.handle_map_clicked)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_button_clicked)

    def handle_map_clicked(self, lat, lng):
        if self._was_clicked:
            self.label.setText(f"latitude: {lat} longitude: {lng}")
        self._was_clicked = False

    def handle_button_clicked(self):
        self._was_clicked = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"
  ></script>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""
  />
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""
  ></script>
  <style>
    #mapid {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapid"></div>
</body>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var map_manager = null;
    var map = L.map("mapid").setView([51.3011, 5.272991], 4);
    L.tileLayer(
      "https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",
      {
        attribution:
          'Map tiles by \u003ca href="http://stamen.com"\u003eStamen Design\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0"\u003eCC BY 3.0\u003c/a\u003e. Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca href="http://openstreetmap.org"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"\u003eCC BY SA\u003c/a\u003e.',
      }
    ).addTo(map);
    map.on("click", function (e) {
      var data = JSON.stringify(e.latlng)
      map_manager.receive_data("click", data);
    });
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
      map_manager = channel.objects.map_manager;
    });
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist or prefer using folium. You can add a custom javascript to your folium map and console.log the click event coordinates. As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875676/8464277) by @eyllanesc you can add javascript console message handler.

Sample Code:

```
import folium
import io
import sys
import json
from branca.element import Element
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView

class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent            

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, line, sourceID):
        print(msg) # Check js errors
        if 'coordinates' in msg:
            self.parent.handleConsoleMessage(msg)  

class FoliumDisplay(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Folium map in PyQt')
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        coordinate = (51.301100, 5.272991)
        m = folium.Map(
        tiles='Stamen Terrain',
        zoom_start=4,
        location=coordinate)

        #Add Custom JS to folium map
        m = self.add_customjs(m)
        # save map data to data object
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)

        webView = QWebEngineView() # start web engine
        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        webView.setPage(page)
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode()) #give html of folium map to webengine
        layout.addWidget(webView)

        #### CEATE SELECT  BUTTON
        self.button_select_point = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bauhaus 93")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_select_point.setFont(font)      
        
        self.button_select_point.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100,20,200,50))
        self.button_select_point.setText("Select one point")     self.button_select_point.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_select_point)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_select_point)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def add_customjs(self, map_object):
        my_js = f"""{map_object.get_name()}.on("click",
                 function (e) {{
                    var data = `{{"coordinates": ${{JSON.stringify(e.latlng)}}}}`;
                    console.log(data)}});"""

        e = Element(my_js)
        html = map_object.get_root()
        html.script.get_root().render()
        # Insert new element or custom JS
        html.script._children[e.get_name()] = e

        return map_object

    def clicked_button_select_point(self):
        print("Clicked")

    def handleConsoleMessage(self, msg):
   
        data = json.loads(msg)       
        lat = data['coordinates']['lat']
        lng = data['coordinates']['lng']
        coords =  f"latitude: {lat} longitude: {lng}"
        self.label.setText(coords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = FoliumDisplay()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```